# Capture TCP communication on a specific port using wireshark

Tags: networking, tcp, tcpip, wireshark

I have build a simple TCP server which listens on port 9999, and it has IP address `202.168.66.1`. I have a TCP client which has the same IP address and connects to the server on the said port.

Now when I start up the server and open [Wireshark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) with display filter `tcp.port==9999` and start the client and send/receive a message nothing get displayed in the capture window in Wireshark...

What am I doing wrong here?

I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: Are the client and server running on the same system?

Comment: yup they are both on the same sys

Comment: Wireshark can capture traffic that goes in and out of a system, but traffic that never leaves the box can be a problem.  If you can separate the client and server, or force the network traffic to run through a gateway or router, then Wireshark should see it.

Comment: im gonna do that now...

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can always (asuming you have a Linux box) [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html) traffic. For example:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 net 202.168.66.1 'port 9999' -s 65535 -w dump.pcap
```

Assuming your interface is eth0 that you are listening on.

Start the client, send/receive messages, and then just open that `dump.pcap` file with Wireshark to see the communication.

Comment: +1 for the info but im using windows machine

Comment: Then you can use [WinDump](http://www.winpcap.org/windump/default.htm) (which is tcpdump ported to Windows, so most of the options are the same, although finding the right interface for the `-i` flag is more effort) or [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) (which also works on various UN\*Xes, as does tcpdump) or [Microsoft Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865) or any of a number of other packet analyzers.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the IP address to connect, or localhost / host name? In that case I guess it could resolve it to the internal IP address (like 127.0.0.1) and the traffic would never be put on a physical interface, and thus not seen by Wireshark.

If the traffic was there, your filter seems like it should pick it up.